# Tooltip hidden inside parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, parent-child

I am using a tooltip plugin.
On this page (https://www.audion.com/product/speedpack-standard/#toggle-id-2) you see available options -> foot pedal.
This one is hoverable and you get tooltip but it needs to overlap the accordeon because now it is hiding in it. How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you provide an example of your code 
 in your question and what you have attempted to complete the task?

Comment: Can You Share Your Code or Code Link?

Comment: I updated my question with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toggles.css` sets `overflow: hidden` on `.single_toggle` and `.toggle_content`. If you override both classes with `overflow: visible` you should be able to see the tooltip again.

In the following screenshot you can see how the tooltip is visible as soon as I apply the `overflow: visible` directly to the two classes mentioned.

[image: Screenshot]